# simple_form + bootstrap, premature validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

My `simple_forms` are showing validation messages before the form is even submitted.

For example, right when you land on the signup page, it's as if you just tried submitting an empty form- the first_name and last_name fields are highlighted in red, with the `can't be blank` error messages next to them.

Adding:

```
required => true
```

(or false) on the simple_form has no effect.

I have validations in my user model. If I remove those model validations, the forms work as expected (adding required: true gives me properly-functioning client-side validation). However, I want to have both client-side and model validations.

Does anybody have a clue as to why validations are triggered when the form is first loaded?

I'm using simple_form 2.0.1 with bootstrap-sass 2.0.1 in my Rails 3.2.2 app. My user form uses the bootstrap styling (`'form-horizontal'`), although when I remove that it still validates prematurely. Also, adding `:novalidate => true` to the form builder has no effect.

Thanks!

Edit: here is the new action is my doctors_controller:

```
def new
    @doctor = Doctor.new
    @user = @doctor.build_user
end
```

(User is a polymorphic association and can belong to multiple models.)

It seems like the user model is getting saved even though I'm using build_user rather than create_user.

### Solved

I updated my model validations to include `on: save`, which solved the problem. It was validating the not-yet-saved user object.

Comment: Can you post your controller actions?

Comment: add your solution as an answer, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my model validations to include on: save, which solved the problem. It was validating the not-yet-saved user object.